# Hide tab with slideUp Jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an 'a' tag, so when I do click over it, It shows other html content (list). The JS code is generic to others tabs...
What I need is when I press the (link) "Title" again, the list gets hide.
What should I do?

I've done this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d90ac70w/)

JS

```
$(".nav_tab>ul>li>a").click(function(event) { 
    $(".nav_tab>ul>li>a").parent().removeClass("activo");
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("activo");

    var capa = $(this).prop('href').split('#');
    $(".nav_tabcontent").slideUp("fast");
    $("#"+capa[1]).slideDown("slow");

    event.preventDefault();
});

$(".nav_tab>ul>li>h3").click(function(event) { 
    $(".nav_tab>ul>li>a").parent().removeClass("activo");

    var o = $(this).parent().find("a");
    o.parent().toggleClass("activo");

    var capa = o.prop('href').split('#');   
    $(".nav_tabcontent").slideUp("fast");
    $("#"+capa[1]).slideToggle("slow");    

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is use jQuery toggle class. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d90ac70w/2/. Just check to see if the div has a class of active.

```
$(".nav_tab>ul>li>h3").click(function (event) {
    $(".nav_tab>ul>li>a").parent().removeClass("activo");
    var o = $(this).parent().find("a");
    o.parent().toggleClass("activo");

    var capa = o.prop('href').split('#');

    if(!$("#" + capa[1]).hasClass('active')){
      $("#" + capa[1]).slideDown(); 
      $("#" + capa[1]).toggleClass('active'); 
    }else{
      $("#" + capa[1]).slideUp();   
      $("#" + capa[1]).toggleClass('active'); 
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Since we are calling the same jQuery selector. We can chain the methods together.

```
$(".nav_tab>ul>li>h3").click(function (event) {
    $(".nav_tab>ul>li>a").parent().removeClass("activo");
    var o = $(this).parent().find("a");
    o.parent().toggleClass("activo");

    var capa = o.prop('href').split('#');

    if(!$("#" + capa[1]).hasClass('active')){
      $("#" + capa[1]).slideDown().toggleClass('active');
    }else{
      $("#" + capa[1]).slideUp().toggleClass('active');
    }

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It's a really good solution, but my js code is for all "sub-menus". I want to make it in a general form for all others html lists :/

Comment: Exactly what I needed it. It has a detail yet... It concatenates with the others submenus (lists)... I will see what can I do. Ty for the support !

Comment: If the code worked for you please accept the answer to help others who has the same problem. @vyplow

Comment: Nice.. @vyplow. Glad I could help.